# Why LinkedIn Social Login Not Returning Email Id With Newly Created App

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

When i am trying with old app then LinkedIn login returning email id with basic profile but when i am trying with new app it's returning only basic profile like (firstName, lastName etc....) but not email Id.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: XXXXXXXXX
    authorize: true 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function liAuth(){
    window.IN.user.authorize().then(function(){
    getProfileData();
});
}
function setLoginBadge(profile) {
        if (!profile) {
              profHTML = "<p>You are not logged in</p>";
        }                       
        document.getElementById("given_name").value =profile.firstName;
        document.getElementById("family_name").value =profile.lastName;
        document.getElementById("email").value = profile.emailAddress;
        document.getElementById("verifyOauthRequestLinkedIn").submit();
        }
function onError(error) {
console.log(error);
}

function getProfileData() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
  .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", 
   "publicProfileUrl","email-address","headline"])
  .result(function(result) {
  setLoginBadge(result.values[0]);
        })
.error(onError);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript SDK is no longer supported, refer: [https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk]

So, the problem is that LinkedIN Api has changed its terms of service and you can no longer get the details like email ID
See available fields here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context]

to get Full profile permission you will have to contact support and validate that your app provides additional functionality